bwip.js replaces "/" character by "-"
Im using bwip.js to create a GS1 datamatrix.
We need to use slash (/) character in batch/lot field.
Everything goes well but when I use barcode reader it reads "-" instead "/".
var data = "(01)08400111114085(17)250128(10)18/03/2025"

return bwipjs.toSVG({
    bcid: 'gs1datamatrix', 
    text: data,
    scale: 1,  
    includetext: false    
});

what i get when reads is "0108400111114085172501281018-03-2025"
I tried to use another character like "-" but this time it changes yo "'"
Solved
The problem was in barcode reader as Mark Warren sugested, so I set the keyboard to spanish and voila! the slash character reads well

I cannot reproduce the issue.  It may be a function of the barcode reader.  For reference, this is what the public API renders:
https://bwipjs-api.metafloor.com/?bcid=gs1datamatrix&text=(01)08400111114085(17)250128(10)18/03/2025&padding=4&backgroundcolor=fff&scale=3
And this is the decode result from zxing:


You are right, it appears that there´s an problem with the barcode reader that changes de character (I tried 3 different readers).
Now I have to find the default code mapping to match barcode reader and see if this works, thanks for your time

The solution was change barcode reader keyboard setting to spanish according to Xenon 1900 barcode reader
